# Find all the city for country with google maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I used Geocoding API to find the the location of Germany.
I want to paint each city in different color.
How I can get the latitude and the Longitude of all the cities for the relevant country ?
Do I need to use KLM or fusion table to get this information ?

Regards,
Yossi

Comment: I tried to do it with Places Library but I didn't succeed

Comment: You need to find a data source with the latitude and longitude of each city in Germany.  You _could_ search on Fusion Tables to see if anyone has uploaded such a dataset.  Your other option is to use something like geonames.org, which has a database of cities for the world...

Comment: Try one of their web services...   http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html